# why doesn't this jsfiddle work? (basic statelistener youtube iframe video)

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

For an already existing youtube iframe, after some research, I found instructions how to set this up.
Normally the youtube api wants you to load the whole video through the api and then work with it, but I have predefined-iframes already in my html.

this jsfiddle is supposed to work but it doesn't.
Can anybody help me why it doesnt work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ss8TL/44/

This is the basic core:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        events: {
            'onStateChange': doawesomestuff
        }
    });
}
```

I got an iframe with id "player".

I know this question possibly might receive some downvotes, sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a little tweak:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
var onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
    });
  }

function onPlayerStateChange() {
 alert("state changed!");
}
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Ss8TL/46/

Comment: funny, seems like the onstatechange api is currently down. not working at all neither on my site nor on the fiddle, that indeed worked before